# What is practical difference between HAL_PPP_Transmit_DMA and HAL_PPP_Transmit_IT?

Tags: stm32, dma, hal

Both procedures allow me to, say, transfer data over UART and call an ISR when job is done. Thus at first glance it seems to me that they do the same thing. Could you please explain what the difference is? I.e. do xxx_IT procedures use DMA (the device) internally? Could you give an example of what xxx_DMA procedures can do what xxx_IT cant and vice versa (personally I know only M2M scenario)? Under which circumstances I should use xxx_DMA instead of xxx_IT?

Comment: do you know what DMA is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DMA works as a separate unit in MCU. It does not take CPU time to transfer data and get data as P__J__  mentioned here. Usually in MCU dma helps to transfer data from various buses like UART,SPI, also from other modules like DAC, ADC, or even between those modules. It is very handy if you need fast transfer of large buffers from RAM and vice versa. For example you need lots of adc samples for oscilloscope. Each irq call may take microsecond, so if you need 1000 samples it is too slow and also each irq call - interrupts MCU job flow while processing useful data.. So DMA is the solution. With IRQ you have to handle data your self, put into buffers and etc. which is also extra time. And if you have TX RX than it take even more time at IRQ. While DMA just writes or reads your buffer at background. Here is a small example:

```
#define BufferSize 50
uint8_t SPI_Buffer_Rx[BufferSize];
uint8_t SPI_Buffer_Tx[BufferSize];
//configuring  SPI

RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_SPI2, ENABLE);
SPI_RxFIFOThresholdConfig(SPI2, SPI_RxFIFOThreshold_HF);
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Slave;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_8b;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_1Edge;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 0;
SPI_Init(SPI2, &SPI_InitStructure);
SPI_CalculateCRC(SPI2, DISABLE);

// RX and TX DMA configuration
/* SPI_SLAVE_Rx_DMA_Channel configuration ---------------------------------*/
RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(SPI_SLAVE_DMA_CLK, ENABLE);
DMA_DeInit(SPI_SLAVE_Rx_DMA_Channel);
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)(&(SPI2->DR));
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t)(&SPI_Buffer_Rx[0]);
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralSRC;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = BufferSize;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Byte;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;
DMA_Init(SPI_SLAVE_Rx_DMA_Channel, &DMA_InitStructure);

/* SPI_SLAVE_Tx_DMA_Channel configuration ---------------------------------*/
DMA_DeInit(SPI_SLAVE_Tx_DMA_Channel);
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)(&(SPI2->DR));
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t)(&SPI_Buffer_Tx[0]);
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralDST;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = BufferSize;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Byte;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_Low;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;
DMA_Init(SPI_SLAVE_Tx_DMA_Channel, &DMA_InitStructure);
```

Not going into details you can see that DMA can handle data FROM SPI data register directly.

**DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)(&(SPI2->DR));**

Also you can set your own buffer which is in RAM. And it will get data from SPI RX via DMA.

**DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t)(&SPI_Buffer_Rx[0]);**

Same with TX and RX as you see.

Also you can control size, type, for ex: FIFO and etc. It depends on your situation.

Definitely you should use DMA when you have more complex architecture or when you need fast data flows, reads,writes. In ST32 dma has concrete channels for each peripheral, so you have decide which peripheral should have DMA which not. Especially it happens when your firmware is complex. But usually there is no lack of DMA channels. So if you have DMA in your MCU and having even moderate data transfers. Why not use it? 
Frequently MCU is stuck with different very handy functions, modules. I don't see arguments why not use those functions? Why anyone should take only old good known approaches when there are lots of new precious ways to make it work??

Answer (score 1):

DMA transfer does the transfer without the core activity "in the background"

Interrupt routine is called every time the char is received or has to be send. Core is busy during every byte transmission or reception.

In your case as you do not know what the DMA is it does not matter for you. As you will not benefit from the DMA transfers you should use the interrupt ones as it is easier to set.